# What is the more efficient algorithm to equalize a vector?

Tags: algorithm, performance

Given a vector of n elements of type integer, what is the more efficient algorithm that produce the minimum number of transformation step resulting in a vector that have all its elements equals, knowing that :

- in a single step, you could transfer at most one point from element to its neighbours ([0, 3, 0] -> [1, 2, 0] is ok but not [0, 3, 0] -> [1, 1, 1]).
- in a single step, an element could receive 2 points : one from its left neighbour and one from the right ([3, 0 , 3] -> [2, 2, 2]).
- first element and last element have only one neighbour, respectively, the 2nd element and the n-1 element.
- an element cannot be negative at any step.

Examples :

```
Given :
 0, 3, 0
Then 2 steps are required :
 1, 2, 0
 1, 1, 1

Given :
 3, 0, 3
Then 1 step is required :
 2, 2, 2

Given :
 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0
Then 3 steps are required :
 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0
 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0
 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

My current algorithm is based on the sums of the integers at each side of an element. But I'm not sure if it produce the minimum steps.

FYI the problem is part of a code contest (created by Criteo http://codeofduty.criteo.com) that is over.

Comment: Your second example should say "1 step is required", right?

Comment: Right. bad copy&paste. thanks

Comment: @astony: *in a single step, you could transfer at least one point from element to its neighbours*.  Do you mean **at most**?

Comment: @astony: Why not provide a sketch of your current algorithm to show what research you've done.

Comment: Sounds exceptionally "homeworky".

Comment: @Mark Right, mistake fixed. I'm working on a sketch. Thanks

Comment: When you can normalise to 1. Since at each step you can transfert only one element. A lower bound of the number of steps is N-1.(it's the number of steps to normalise your largest element).

Comment: A good strategy with such problem would be to "divide and conquer" since you can move things simultaneously.

Comment: @Orbling Not homework, it's related to a code contest. It's over and I try to find a better solution. I'm working on a sketch of my solution like suggested by @Mark. But you are right it sounds like ;)

Comment: @astony: Best to mention that in the question, as you say, it sounds like it.  Homework is supposed to be marked up you see, site policy.  So the need to clear up the matter is present.

Comment: Is it allowed for numbers to become less than zero during the process?

Comment: @Orbling I added a mention of the context, i.e code contest. thanks

Comment: @Orbling: There is no "site policy" that says homework *must* be identified as such, particularly not by the asker.  Each volunteer chooses what he or she does and does not want to respond to.  The `homework` tag is found useful by some to gear their responses more toward teaching than solving, and that's their prerogative, but it's their choice.  Please try not to make SO seem like a bureaucracy.

Comment: @Pavel No. Negative integers are forbidden. Question fixed. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Peters: Please see this guidance on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812 - Particularly: *"Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster. Do this by mentioning that it is homework in the question text..."*  Incidentally, I've always found SO very bureaucratic.

Comment: @Orbling: 1) That is guidance for helping an *asker* get a better response.  It should **in no way** be construed as policy.  Look right at the top of the answer: *This post is not the official position of the Stack Overflow administrators, but rather a community-edited effort to provide clear guidelines on how to respond to homework. Individual community members can of course use their own judgment.*.  2) astony's question is NOT homework, so that doesn't apply to him.  He wasn't trying to hide that it's homework, and badgering him into explicitly saying that is, IMO, tending to bureacracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way. You know the sum of the array, so you know the target number in each cell.
Thus you also know the target sum for each subarray.
Then iterate through the array and on each step you make a desicion:

1. Move 1 to the left: if the sum up to the previous element is less then desired.
2. Move 1 to the right: if the sum up to the current element is more than desired
3. Don't do anything: if both of the above are false

Repeat this until no more changes are made (i.e. you only applied 3 for each of the elements).

```
    public static int F(int[] ar)
    {
        int iter = -1;
        bool finished = false;
        int total = ar.Sum();

        if (ar.Length == 0 || total % ar.Length != 0) return 0; //can't do it
        int target = total / ar.Length;

        int sum = 0;

        while (!finished)
        {
            iter++;
            finished = true;
            bool canMoveNext = true;

            //first element
            if (ar[0] > target)
            {
                finished = false;
                ar[0]--;
                ar[1]++;

                canMoveNext = ar[1] != 1;
            }

            sum = ar[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < ar.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!canMoveNext)
                {
                    canMoveNext = true;
                    sum += ar[i];
                    continue;
                }

                if (sum < i * target && ar[i] > 0)
                {
                    finished = false;
                    ar[i]--;
                    ar[i - 1]++;
                    sum++;
                }
                else if (sum + ar[i] > (i + 1) * target && ar[i] > 0) //this can't happen for the last element so we are safe
                {
                    finished = false;
                    ar[i]--;
                    ar[i + 1]++;

                    canMoveNext = ar[i + 1] != 1;
                }

                sum += ar[i];
            }
        }

        return iter;
    }
```

Comment: For the 3rd example, you code give the right number of steps but with an invalid intermediary step (in contradiction with my 3rd constraint) : Given [4,0,0,0,4,0,0,0] Then 3 steps are required [3,0,0,1,3,0,0,1], [2,0,1,1,2,0,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. I will try to fix it myself. Thanks whatever

Comment: Thanks but now you do it in 4 steps instead of 3 [3,1,0,1,3,0,0,0] [2,1,1,1,2,1,0,0] [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0] [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: Hm... No, it's 3, I just ran it: |4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0|,|3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0|,|2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0|,|1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|

Comment: I'm afraid your algorithm doesn't work for the first example, it gives only 1 step.

Comment: Ha, got it! You forgot the "special case" (i.e : `you could transfer at most one point from element to its neighbours`)

Comment: No, I didn't forget. Just run the first example - it gives 2. How do you guys get different results. Don't you just copy paste the code?

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. Your C# code works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've got an idea. I'm not sure it produces the optimal result, but it feels like it can.

Suppose the initial vector is the N-sized vector `V`. You need two additional N-sized vector :

- In the `L` vector, you sum elements starting from the left : `L[n] = sum(i=0;i<=n)  V[n]`
- In the `R` vector, you sum elements starting from the right: `R[n] = sum(i=n;i<N) V[n]`

You finally need one last specific value : the sum of all the elements of V is supposed to be equal to `k*N` with `k` an integer. And you have `L[N-1] == R[0] == k*N`

Let's take the `L` vector. The idea is that for any n, consider the `V` vector divided in two parts, one from 0 to n, and the other contains the rest. If `L[n]<n*k`, then you've got to "fill" the first part with values from the second part. And vice versa if `L[n]>n*k`. **If `L[i]==i*k`, then congratulations, the problem can be subdivided in two subproblems!** There is no reason for any value from the second vector to be transferred to the first vector, and vice-versa.

Then, the algorithm is simple : for every value of n, check the value of `L[n]-n*k` and `R[n]-(N-n)*k` and act accordingly. There is just one special case, if `L[n]-n*k>0` **and** `R[n]-(N-n)*k>0` (there is a high value at V[n]), you must empty it in both directions. Just choose at random a direction to tranfer.

Of course, don't forget to update `L` and `R` accordingly.

Edit : In fact, it seems that you only need the `L` vector. Here is a simplified algorithm.

- If `L[n]==n*k`, don't do anything
- If `L[n]<n*k`, then transfer one value from `V[n+1]` to `V[n]` (if `V[n+1]`>0 of course)
- If `L[n]>n*k`, then transfer one value from `V[n]` to `V[n+1]` (if `V[n]`>0 of course)

And (the special case) if you're asked to tranfer from `V[n]` to `V[n-1]` and `V[n+1]`, just tranfer randomly once, it won't change the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sam Hocevar, for the following alternative implementation to the fiver's one :

```
public static int F(int[] ar)
{
    int total = ar.Sum();

    if (ar.Length == 0 || total % ar.Length != 0) return 0; //can't do it
    int target = total / ar.Length;

    int[] left = new int[ar.Length];
    int[] right = new int[ar.Length];
    int maxshifts = 0;
    int delta = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
    {
        left[i] = delta < 0 ? -delta : 0;
        delta += ar[i] - target;
        right[i] = delta > 0 ? delta : 0;
        if (left[i] + right[i] > maxshifts) {
            maxshifts = left[i] + right[i];
        }    
    }

    for (int iter = 0; iter < maxshifts; iter++)
    {
        int lastleftadd = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
            if (left[i] != 0  && ar[i] != 0)
            {
                ar[i]--;
                ar[i - 1]++;
                left[i]--;
            }
            else if (right[i] != 0 && ar[i] != 0
                              && (ar[i] != 1 || lastleftadd != i))
            {
                ar[i]--;
                ar[i + 1]++;
                lastleftadd = i + 1;
                right[i]--;
            }
        }
    }

    return maxshifts;
}
```